# Extract filepaths of .MP4 files in subfolders of main folder to textfile

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I am on Mac. I want to use terminal or something to extract the filepaths of the .MP4 files within a folder with multiple levels of subfolders. I have a main folder that has subfolders. Each subfolder has its own subfolders. Eventually in this line, there are .MP4 files. I want a text file with the filepath of each .MP4 file, preferably with commas or semicolons between. Can you help me?

I looked into a few options, but they were either for Windows or not that helpful. The dir command in Windows seemed relevant perhaps.

Comment: I tested this with Bash, could you try on your system?: `find /path_to_your_main_folder -iname *.mp4 -printf '%p, ' > ~/file.txt`. `file.txt` will be saved in your home directory (`~/`).

Comment: @Éric it yielded the following: find: -printf: unknown primary or operator. Then I looked it up and it said I couldn't use printf until I did "brew install findutils". I did that. Then it said use gfind instead of find. So I did: gfind /mainfolder -iname *.mp4 -printf '%p, ' > ~/file.txt. file.txt
gfind: paths must precede expression: `file.txt'

Comment: can you try: `gfind /path_to_your_main_folder -iname "*.mp4" -fprintf ~/file.txt '%p, '`

Comment: Hi @Éric, it is having trouble with my /path_to_main_folder. If I am running it in the main folder, what would I put there?

Comment: Hi @Helppleaseme, I posted a detailed answer with an improved command, and explaining it by the way. Please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering this file structure:

```
/
├── Users
│   └── You
│       └── main_dir
│           ├── subdir_1
│           │   └── subdir_1-1
│           │       └── movie_A.mp4
│           ├── subdir_2
.           │   └── movie_B.mp4
.           └── subdir_3
.               └── movie_C.mp4
```

After installing `findutils` with this command:

```
brew install findutils
```

then running this command in the terminal:

```
gfind /Users/You/main_dir -iname "*.mp4" -fprintf ~/file.txt "'%p', "
```

should fill `~/file.txt` with this content:

> `'/Users/You/main_dir/subdir_1/subdir_1-1/movie_A.mp4', '/Users/You/main_dir/subdir_2/movie_B.mp4', '/Users/You/main_dir/subdir_3/movie_C.mp4',`

**Some insights:**

The `-fprintf` option of `gfind` (or `find`) prints the result in the specified format (here `'%p',` ) to the specified file (here `~/file.txt`).

In the `'%p',`  format:

- `%p` uses the path and name of the found items, starting from the beginning of the searched path (here `/Users/You/main_dir`, implying that `%p` will start from the root `/`),
- the above is enclosed between single quotes (`'`) to deal with possible spaces and/or commas in the file paths,
- then the characters `,`  (comma, space) are appended.